# ASP.NET Core 7.0 - configure Kestrel applicationURL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

.netAt the moment, this is the code I have:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseWindowsService(options => {
  options.ServiceName = "My Server";
}).ConfigureServices(services => {
  services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
});
...
```

and

```
"profiles": {
    "MyProj": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:5000;",
```

How do I instead set `applicationUrl` (with port) in the builder configuration?

I saw various answers but not sure how to proceed with ASP.NET Core 7.0, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0) it says to use:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(listenOptions =>
    {
        // ...
    });
});
```

but I am not sure how to set the `applicationUrl` and if `WebHost` is what I need (as I am using a Windows service as above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to use [WebApplicationBuilder.WebHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder.webhost?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in combination with the Windows Service functionality, as the `WebHost` still runs when using `WebApplicationBuilder`.

Because of that, I think the simplest method for setting the URL for your scenario is to use [`UseUrls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.useurls):

```cs
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
```

This doesn't require setting anything that's specific to Kestrel, yet the configuration does make its way down *to* Kestrel.

---

To configure Kestrel directly, you can use [`ConfigureKestrel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderkestrelextensions.configurekestrel), as suggested in your question. To set the URL this way, use the [`Listen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.listen) method:

```cs
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(kestrelServerOptions =>
{
    kestrelServerOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001);
});
```

There are a number of options for configuring the URL, such as configuring HTTPS, using [DnsEndPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dnsendpoint), etc. This approach offers a lot more flexibility, but if you simply want to set the URL programmatically, I'd still recommend the `UseUrls` approach.

Answer (score -1):

Just `run the following command in cmd` [start-url-in-aspnet-core](https://procodeguide.com/programming/how-to-set-start-url-in-aspnet-core/)

```
setx ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://127.0.0.1:5001;https://127.0.0.1:5002"
```